# Header of data file disappears when sorting

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, csv

I have a csv file with rows of data. The first row is headers for the columns.
I'd like to sort the data by some parameter (specifically, the first column), but of course keep the header where it is.
When I do the following, the header disappears completely and is not included in the output file.
Can anyone please advise how to keep the header but skip it and sort the rest of the rows?
(for fwiw, the first column is a mix of numbers and letters).

Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
import csv
import operator

sankey = open('rawforsankey.csv', "rb")
raw_reader = csv.reader(sankey)


raw_data = []
for row in raw_reader:
    raw_data.append(row)


raw_data_sorted = sorted(raw_data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))

myfiletest = open('newfiletest.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfiletest,quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)

wr.writerows(raw_data_sorted)


sankey.close()
myfiletest.close()
```

EDIT: should mention I tried this variation in the code:

```
raw_data_sorted = sorted(raw_data[1:], key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

but got the same result

Comment: I guess it was left from some previous testing...

Comment: Well, the output I get doesn't have 1,2,3.... in the first column, and the first row - of headers - disappears. Just removed the enumerate and still the same thing happens to the header.

Comment: I edited the code to remove the enumerate... tnx

Answer (score 2):

You sorted all data, including the header, which means it is still there but perhaps in the *middle* of your resulting output somewhere.

This is how you'd sort a CSV on one column, preserving the header:

```
import csv
import operator

with open('rawforsankey.csv', "rb") as sankey:
    raw_reader = csv.reader(sankey)
    header = next(raw_reader, None)
    sorted_data = sorted(raw_reader, operator.itemgetter(0))

with open('newfiletest.csv', 'wb') as myfiletest:
    wr = csv.writer(myfiletest, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    if header:
        wr.writerow(header)
    wr.writerows(sorted_data)
```

Just remember that sorting is done *lexicographically* as all columns are strings. So `10` sorts before `9`, for example. Use a more specific sorting key if your data is numeric, for example.

Comment: tnx. Can you please explain why my code doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: @Optimesh: the only *logical* change I made is to read the header first (`header = next(raw_reader, None)` takes one row, which is then written first to the output file).

Comment: @Optimesh: the rest is just best practices; you can call `sorted()` directly on the CSV reader object, using `with` to ensure the file objects are closed automatically.

Comment: Then the output I get is weird, no? How would you do it if you wanted to keep the original _and_ create a sorted version? Thanks for your help Martijn

Comment: I don't see how the output you get is weird; the code you posted will sort the data, and output it it to a new file. Sorting happens as strings, your header is probably sorted to the end or middle somewhere.

Comment: Your original file is untouched, still unsorted.

Comment: @Optimesh: then run your original code, *print* `raw_data` and look for the header there. It won't be there either. *Nothing* in your code will lose a header row.

Comment: Nope, it's there, when I ==> print raw_data[0] I get the header row. This strange behavior is part of the reason I posted the question. I want to understand better what's wrong, not just get the right way to do it.

Comment: Then the **row is still there after sorting**, you just didn't look for it correctly. I am **really** confident about this, btw.

Comment: @Optimesh: *does my code work*? BTW, if you sorted the data minus the first row (with the slice you added in an edit), did you remember to write it to the output file?

Comment: It's not there. Opened it in excel, searched for it, it's not there.

Comment: Without seeing your data I cannot tell you where you went wrong; the code you posted will not ever remove a row. Perhaps you didn't share all the code?

Comment: 1) You are right - I forgot to add the header when I sliced the data, and then it works.
2) There is a bunch of code in the middle, but honestly I doesn't affect the data. The code is verbatim from the start until after "raw_data_sorted...". I just added the sorted_ part recently to try to improve the performance of the code I omitted here. So, at this stage it's untouched. Never called the sorted part. Just added the bottom part to write it to file.

Comment: Always rerun the code you post in a question to see if you still have the right understanding. :-) Especially when you've been experimenting a few times, you can no longer be certain that the output you have was produced by what you posted.

Comment: You are right. I just assumed that since I don't work on the sorted list the code in the middle doesn't matter. But you know what happens when one assumes... :) So now my confusion is even greater since I don't know why I get other results when I never refer to the sorted part again in my code (other than printing it to file)